# osmnx: g.node is deprecated but g.nodes leads to error

Tags: python, networkx, osmnx

I am trying to run this sample code. It says "AttributeError: 'MultiDiGraph' object has no attribute 'node'" and I found that g.node is deprecated and is replaced with g.nodes. But if I just change it to g.nodes, it gives an other error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/anderledani/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/snaptoroadtest.py", line 12, in <module>
    nn = min((u, v), key=lambda n: ox.distance.great_circle_vec(lat, lng, G.nodes[n]['y'], G.nodes[n]['x']))
  File "/home/anderledani/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/snaptoroadtest.py", line 12, in <lambda>
    nn = min((u, v), key=lambda n: ox.distance.great_circle_vec(lat, lng, G.nodes[n]['y'], G.nodes[n]['x']))
  File "/home/anderledani/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py", line 187, in __getitem__
    return self._nodes[n]
KeyError: 0
```

The code I am trying to run:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)

# get graph and define a reference point
G = ox.graph_from_point((13.743942, 100.570006), network_type='drive', dist=350, simplify=True)
lat = 13.744001
lng = 100.570457

# get nearest node incident to nearest edge to reference point
geom, u, v = ox.distance.get_nearest_edge(G, (lat, lng))
nn = min((u, v), key=lambda n: ox.distance.great_circle_vec(lat, lng, G.nodes[n]['y'], G.nodes[n]['x']))

# plot the reference point and this nearest node
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G, node_color='#999999', show=False, close=False)
ax.scatter(lng, lat, c='r', marker='x')
ax.scatter(G.nodes[nn]['x'], G.nodes[nn]['y'], c='r', s=50, zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `osmnx` the [`get_nearest_edge`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.get_nearest_edge) method is marked as deprecated.

However, I think you can directly get your desired variable `nn` - I guess it's nearest node - with: [`nearest_nodes`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_nodes):

```
nn = ox.distance.nearest_nodes(G, lat, lng)
```

If you want the nearest node from the nearest edge, update to the new method [`nearest_edges`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.distance.nearest_edges)

```
(u, v, key) = nearest_edges(G, lat, lng)
```

Second answer containing the code of the asker: [How to find nearest node along nearest edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68257014/how-to-find-nearest-node-along-nearest-edge)

Comment: I'm not only searching for the nearest node, but the nearest node along the nearest edge.

Comment: In that case try the method nearest_edges, (I've added above), and check what is the content of the return `(u,v,key)`.

Comment: Is u and v the id of the two nodes on the two ends of the edge?

Comment: According to the documentation in my above code it should be the two nodes of the edge. The key should specify the specific edge (since the underlying graph is a Multigraph).

Comment: Then can I decide which node is closer with euclidean_dist_vec function?

Comment: Yes Euclidean distance or Harvestine distance, both methods should work (and be probably very similar for short distances)