# How to find nearest node along nearest edge?

Tags: python, graph, routes, networkx, osmnx

I am using this script from here: [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/find-and-plot-your-optimal-path-using-plotly-and-networkx-in-python-17e75387b873)

I want to add new functionality to it. I want it to define starting node on the graph not only by finding the closest node (because that produces odd results like finding the closest node on an other road) but finding the closest and and the closest node along that edge.
My code is available below. I created the findnearestnodeonnearestedge function which should do the work but it doesn't work.
It finds the same node for the starting and destination point, even though they are far from each other...
I am using the newest versions of all packages so you can try the code easily.

Thank you for help

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np


def findnearestnodeonnearestedge(Gr, pointin):

    u, v, key = ox.distance.nearest_edges(G, pointin[0], pointin[1])

    n1 = Gr.nodes[u]
    n2 = Gr.nodes[v]

    d1 = ox.distance.euclidean_dist_vec(pointin[0], pointin[1], n1['x'], n1['y'])
    d2 = ox.distance.euclidean_dist_vec(pointin[0], pointin[1], n2['x'], n2['y'])

    if d1 < d2:
        nodeid = u
    else:
        nodeid = v

    return nodeid


state = ox.geocode_to_gdf('Georgia, US')
ax = ox.project_gdf(state).plot(fc='gray', ec='none')
_ = ax.axis('off')

# Defining the map boundaries
north, east, south, west = 33.798, -84.378, 33.763, -84.422

# Downloading the map as a graph object
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north, south, east, west, network_type = 'drive')

# Plotting the map graph
ox.plot_graph(G)

# Displaying the 3rd node
list(G.nodes(data=True))[2]

# Displaying the 1st edge
list(G.edges(data=True))[1]

# Displaying the shape of edge using the geometry
list(G.edges(data=True))[1][2]['geometry']

# define origin and desination locations
origin_point = (33.787201, -84.405076)
destination_point = (33.764135, -84.394980)

# get the nearest nodes to the locations
origin_node = findnearestnodeonnearestedge(G, origin_point)
destination_node = findnearestnodeonnearestedge(G, destination_point)

# printing the closest node id to origin and destination points
origin_node, destination_node

# Finding the optimal path
route = nx.shortest_path(G, origin_node, destination_node, weight = 'length')
route

# getting coordinates of the nodes

# we will store the longitudes and latitudes in following list
long = []
lat = []

for i in route:
    point = G.nodes[i]
    long.append(point['x'])
    lat.append(point['y'])


def plot_path(lat, long, origin_point, destination_point):
    """
    Given a list of latitudes and longitudes, origin
    and destination point, plots a path on a map

    Parameters
    ----------
    lat, long: list of latitudes and longitudes
    origin_point, destination_point: co-ordinates of origin
    and destination
    Returns
    -------
    Nothing. Only shows the map.
    """

    # adding the lines joining the nodes
    fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        name="Path",
        mode="lines",
        lon=long,
        lat=lat,
        marker={'size': 10},
        line=dict(width=4.5, color='blue')))

    # adding source marker
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        name="Source",
        mode="markers",
        lon=[origin_point[1]],
        lat=[origin_point[0]],
        marker={'size': 12, 'color': "red"}))

    # adding destination marker
    fig.add_trace(go.Scattermapbox(
        name="Destination",
        mode="markers",
        lon=[destination_point[1]],
        lat=[destination_point[0]],
        marker={'size': 12, 'color': 'green'}))

    # getting center for plots:
    lat_center = np.mean(lat)
    long_center = np.mean(long)

    # defining the layout using mapbox_style
    fig.update_layout(mapbox_style="stamen-terrain", mapbox_center_lat=30, mapbox_center_lon=-80)
    fig.update_layout(margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
                      mapbox={
                          'center': {'lat': lat_center, 'lon': long_center},
                          'zoom': 13})

    fig.show()

plot_path(lat, long, origin_point, destination_point)

# Getting the start and end node of this part
start_node=route[-7]
end_node=route[-6]

# Getting the edge connecting these nodes and storing it as a list in z to maintain the data structure of G.edges
z = []

for i in list(G.edges(data=True)):
    if (i[0]==start_node) & (i[1]==end_node):
        z.append(i)

z[0][2]['geometry']

def node_list_to_path(G, node_list):
    """
    Given a list of nodes, return a list of lines that together follow the path
    defined by the list of nodes.
    Parameters
    ----------
    G : networkx multidigraph
    route : list
        the route as a list of nodes
    Returns
    -------
    lines : list of lines given as pairs ( (x_start, y_start), (x_stop, y_stop) )
    """
    edge_nodes = list(zip(node_list[:-1], node_list[1:]))
    lines = []
    for u, v in edge_nodes:
        # if there are parallel edges, select the shortest in length
        data = min(G.get_edge_data(u, v).values(), key=lambda x: x['length'])

        # if it has a geometry attribute (ie, a list of line segments)
        if 'geometry' in data:
            # add them to the list of lines to plot
            xs, ys = data['geometry'].xy
            lines.append(list(zip(xs, ys)))
        else:
            # if it doesn't have a geometry attribute, the edge is a straight
            # line from node to node
            x1 = G.nodes[u]['x']
            y1 = G.nodes[u]['y']
            x2 = G.nodes[v]['x']
            y2 = G.nodes[v]['y']
            line = [(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]
            lines.append(line)
    return lines

# getting the list of coordinates from the path (which is a list of nodes)
lines = node_list_to_path(G, route)

long2 = []
lat2 = []

for i in range(len(lines)):
    z = list(lines[i])
    l1 = list(list(zip(*z))[0])
    l2 = list(list(zip(*z))[1])
    for j in range(len(l1)):
        long2.append(l1[j])
        lat2.append(l2[j])

print("Length of lat: ", len(lat))
print("Length of lat2: ", len(lat2))

plot_path(lat2, long2, origin_point, destination_point)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that in the graph coordinates are stored in reverse order. So all pointin[0] and pointin[1] in the function should be reversed and then it will work